# Error CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE in JOCL sampels

Tags: java, opencl, gpu, jocl

I need to use OpenCl with java So I have chosen  JOCL
when I wanted to try jocl samples ( http://www.jocl.org/samples/samples.html) I always find this error when compiling the samples.

for example the sample (JOCLSample_1_2_KernelArgs.java) shows this errors:

```
**Exception in thread "main" org.jocl.CLException: CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
at org.jocl.CL.checkResult(CL.java:686)
at org.jocl.CL.clCreateContext(CL.java:3803)
at org.jocl.JOCLSample_1_2_KernelArgs.defaultInitialization(JOCLSample_1_2_KernelArgs.java:177)
at org.jocl.JOCLSample_1_2_KernelArgs.main(JOCLSample_1_2_KernelArgs.java:42)**
```

I am sure that my drivers works well.

when I compile the sample JOCLDeviceQuery.java (which shows Queries and prints information about all available devices.)

**This is the result:**

```
Number of platforms: 4
Number of devices in platform Intel(R) OpenCL: 2
Number of devices in platform NVIDIA CUDA: 1
Number of devices in platform Experimental OpenCL 2.0 CPU Only Platform: 1
Number of devices in platform AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing: 1
--- Info for device        Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz: ---
CL_DEVICE_NAME:                    Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz
CL_DEVICE_VENDOR:           Intel(R) Corporation
CL_DRIVER_VERSION:          5.0.0.57
CL_DEVICE_TYPE:             CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS:        4
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS: 3
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES:      8192 / 8192 / 8192 
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE:      8192
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY:      1800 MHz
CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS:         64
CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE:       998 MByte
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE:      3995 MByte
CL_DEVICE_ERROR_CORRECTION_SUPPORT: no
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_TYPE:       global
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE:       32 KByte
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE: 128 KByte
CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:     CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE
CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:     CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE
CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT:        1
CL_DEVICE_MAX_READ_IMAGE_ARGS:      480
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WRITE_IMAGE_ARGS:     480
CL_DEVICE_SINGLE_FP_CONFIG:     CL_FP_DENORM CL_FP_INF_NAN CL_FP_ROUND_TO_NEAREST 
CL_DEVICE_2D_MAX_WIDTH          16384
CL_DEVICE_2D_MAX_HEIGHT         16384
CL_DEVICE_3D_MAX_WIDTH          2048
CL_DEVICE_3D_MAX_HEIGHT         2048
CL_DEVICE_3D_MAX_DEPTH          2048
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_<t>    CHAR 1, SHORT 1, INT 1, LONG 1, FLOAT 1, DOUBLE 1


--- Info for device Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000: ---
CL_DEVICE_NAME:             Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
CL_DEVICE_VENDOR:           Intel(R) Corporation
CL_DRIVER_VERSION:          9.17.10.2828
CL_DEVICE_TYPE:             CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS:        16
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS: 3
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES:      512 / 512 / 512 
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE:      512
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY:      350 MHz
CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS:         64
CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE:       406 MByte
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE:      1624 MByte
CL_DEVICE_ERROR_CORRECTION_SUPPORT: no
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_TYPE:       local
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE:       64 KByte
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE: 64 KByte
CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:     CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE
CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT:        1
CL_DEVICE_MAX_READ_IMAGE_ARGS:      128
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WRITE_IMAGE_ARGS:     8
CL_DEVICE_SINGLE_FP_CONFIG:     CL_FP_INF_NAN CL_FP_ROUND_TO_NEAREST CL_FP_ROUND_TO_ZERO CL_FP_ROUND_TO_INF 
CL_DEVICE_2D_MAX_WIDTH          16384
CL_DEVICE_2D_MAX_HEIGHT         16384
CL_DEVICE_3D_MAX_WIDTH          2048
CL_DEVICE_3D_MAX_HEIGHT         2048
CL_DEVICE_3D_MAX_DEPTH          2048
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_<t>    CHAR 1, SHORT 1, INT 1, LONG 1, FLOAT 1, DOUBLE 0


--- Info for device GeForce GT 630M: ---
CL_DEVICE_NAME:             GeForce GT 630M
CL_DEVICE_VENDOR:           NVIDIA Corporation
CL_DRIVER_VERSION:          352.86
CL_DEVICE_TYPE:             CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS:        2
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS: 3
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES:      1024 / 1024 / 64 
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE:      1024
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY:      1600 MHz
CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS:         64
CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE:       256 MByte
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE:      1024 MByte
CL_DEVICE_ERROR_CORRECTION_SUPPORT: no
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_TYPE:       local
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE:       48 KByte
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE: 64 KByte
CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:     CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE
CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:     CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE
CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT:        1
CL_DEVICE_MAX_READ_IMAGE_ARGS:      128
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WRITE_IMAGE_ARGS:     8
CL_DEVICE_SINGLE_FP_CONFIG:     CL_FP_DENORM CL_FP_INF_NAN CL_FP_ROUND_TO_NEAREST CL_FP_ROUND_TO_ZERO CL_FP_ROUND_TO_INF CL_FP_FMA CL_FP_CORRECTLY_ROUNDED_DIVIDE_SQRT 
CL_DEVICE_2D_MAX_WIDTH          16384
CL_DEVICE_2D_MAX_HEIGHT         16384
CL_DEVICE_3D_MAX_WIDTH          2048
CL_DEVICE_3D_MAX_HEIGHT         2048
CL_DEVICE_3D_MAX_DEPTH          2048
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_<t>    CHAR 1, SHORT 1, INT 1, LONG 1, FLOAT 1, DOUBLE 1


--- Info for device        Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz: ---
CL_DEVICE_NAME:                    Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz
CL_DEVICE_VENDOR:           Intel(R) Corporation
CL_DRIVER_VERSION:          6.0.0.1049
CL_DEVICE_TYPE:             CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS:        4
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS: 3
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES:      8192 / 8192 / 8192 
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE:      8192
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY:      1800 MHz
CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS:         64
CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE:       998 MByte
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE:      3995 MByte
CL_DEVICE_ERROR_CORRECTION_SUPPORT: no
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_TYPE:       global
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE:       32 KByte
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE: 128 KByte
CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:     CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE
CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:     CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE
CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT:        1
CL_DEVICE_MAX_READ_IMAGE_ARGS:      480
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WRITE_IMAGE_ARGS:     480
CL_DEVICE_SINGLE_FP_CONFIG:     CL_FP_DENORM CL_FP_INF_NAN CL_FP_ROUND_TO_NEAREST 
CL_DEVICE_2D_MAX_WIDTH          16384
CL_DEVICE_2D_MAX_HEIGHT         16384
CL_DEVICE_3D_MAX_WIDTH          2048
CL_DEVICE_3D_MAX_HEIGHT         2048
CL_DEVICE_3D_MAX_DEPTH          2048
CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_<t>    CHAR 1, SHORT 1, INT 1, LONG 1, FLOAT 1, DOUBLE 1


--- Info for device        Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz
```

**what is the solution for my problem???????how can I compile jocl samples ???**

Comment: Does the most basic sample, http://jocl.org/samples/JOCLSample.java , work for you? Note that the others may require OpenCL versions or features that are not supported by the respective device. Which device do you want to use, actually?

Comment: I want to use GPU and CPU but for now it works just when I change all to GPU in ( final long deviceType = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU;)

Comment: Then the error can probably (as an educated guess) be summarized: It basically works, **but** the compile flag `"-cl-kernel-arg-info"` (which uses an OpenCL 1.2 feature) is **not** supported by some of the CPU devices. (E.g. some of the CPU devices may only have OpenCL 1.1 or lower)

Comment: Then what is the solution???? I wonder if I can work with jocl functions which are compatible with OpenCL1.1??? Is there any possibility to do this

Comment: Yes, sure. When you have a device that supports OpenCL 1.1, then you can use the OpenCL 1.1 functions with JOCL. If you have a device that supports OpenCL 1.2, then you can use the OpenCL 1.2 functions with JOCL. The error in the example (likely) only appeared because you tried to use OpenCL 1.2 functions with a device that only supports OpenCL 1.1.

Comment: Thank you for the calrification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  changing the device type from CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL

to CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU   or CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU

In OpenCL, it's better  not to mix device types

see the  [example code](http://www.jocl.org/samples/JOCLSample_1_2_KernelArgs.java)

```
public class JOCLSample_1_2_KernelArgs
{
    // The platform, device type and device number that will be used
    private static final int platformIndex = 0;
    private static final long deviceType = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL;
    ...
```

Comment: I tried, deviceType = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU;                                          the result is:                                                                                                Platform version: OpenCL 1.2 
Exception in thread "main" org.jocl.CLException: CL_INVALID_BUILD_OPTIONS
 at org.jocl.CL.clBuildProgram(CL.java:9364)
 at org.jocl.JOCLSample_1_2_KernelArgs.main(JOCLSample_1_2_KernelArgs.java:51)

Comment: line 51:       clBuildProgram(program, 0, null, "-cl-kernel-arg-info", null, null);

Comment: This is a new problem. The code has successfully created   the device. It now has a problem building the kernel.

Comment: It works when I change   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU;  but just in some classes

Comment: for now 
it's enough Thank you Tim chils